# How to get ienumerated element from sister collection

Tags: c#, collections

I often use two related collections and want to access the corresponding elements in a foreach loop.

But, there is no ".Index" property, is there a direct way of doing this, WITHOUT incrementing a counter?

```
     public void PrepareData()
        {
            var lines = ReadAllLines(@"\\tsclient\T\Bbtra\wapData.txt");
            var headers = lines[0].Split(',');
            var values = lines.Last().Split(',');


            foreach(var value in values.Skip(1))
            {
                string message = "Data: "+headers[value.Index]+' '+value
            }
       }
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do it with IndexOf

```
var lines = ReadAllLines(@"\\tsclient\T\Bbtra\wapData.txt");
var headers = lines[0].Split(',');
var values = lines.Last().Split(',');


foreach(var value in values.Skip(1))
{
    string message = "Data: " + headers[Array.IndexOf(values, value)] + ' ' + value;
}
```

or maybe with iterators :

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"\\tsclient\T\Bbtra\wapData.txt");
var headers = lines[0].Split(',');
var values = lines.Last().Split(',');

var e1 = headers.GetEnumerator();
var e2 = values.GetEnumerator();

while(e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
{
    string message = "Data: " + e1.Current.ToString() + ' ' + e2.Current.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I have to convert "ToLIst", was hoping there was a more direct way

Comment: Array.IndexOf(values, value), no convert toList

Comment: @cdie Array.IndexOf(values, value) is perfect! This does not have to have great performance, and to me the "readability" is high - thank you. Sorry that others did not like the idea

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and an anonymous type:

```
string[] names={"Rod", "Jane", "Freddy"}
int[] ages={28,32,26;};

var pairs=names.Zip(ages, (name,age) => new{Name=name, Age=age});
foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
  string name=pair.Name;
  string age=pair.Age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant, use [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) overloading with index like

```
public void PrepareData()
{
    var lines = ReadAllLines(@"\\tsclient\T\Bbtra\wapData.txt");
    var headers = lines[0].Split(',');
    var values = lines.Last().Split(',').Select((el,index)=>new {value=el, index=index});


    foreach(var value in values.Skip(1))
    {
        string message = "Data: "+headers[value.index]+' '+value.value
    }
}
```

depends on data in headers and values, better variant can be

```
public void PrepareData()
{
    var lines = ReadAllLines(@"\\tsclient\T\Bbtra\wapData.txt");
    var headers = lines[0].Split(',');
    var values = lines.Last().Split(',');


    foreach(var item in values.Skip(1).Select((el,index)=>new {value=el, index=index}))
    {
        string message = "Data: "+headers[item.index]+' '+item.value
    }
}
```

Comment: _Goddamit_ beaten by seconds :p +1 BTW

Comment: @BinaryWorrier, interestingly, methinks, your version is more correct :-)

Comment: Shame that Index is not provided as standard. Seems useful property to me.

Comment: @Grundy: Feel free to lift the better bits and use them in your answer bud

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want a [`.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
var pairs = headers.Zip(values, 
   (header, value) => new Tuple<string, string>(header, value));
```